# Javascript repeating if statements better solution?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 inputs and the code checks if they are empty and if they are then the variable values are added to the inputs.

So I have 3 variables with values:

```
var input1text = "something here";
var input2text = "something else here";
var input3text = "something else 2 here";
```

So when the page loads, I check if the inputs are empty and if they are I add the variable values to the inputs.

Like this:

```
if($('#input1').val() == '') {

    //Add input1text text to it

}

if($('#input2').val() == '') {

    //Add input2text text to it

}


if($('#input3').val() == '') {

    //Add input3text text to it

}
```

My question is, it having multiple `if`s the most elegant way to do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: why would the other 2 execute if you set text to input in the first one itself?

Comment: can `input1text`, `input2text` be empty?

Comment: All I see is 3 of the same conditions with some comments.

Comment: It needs to check all of them and if empty, then add the variables. The code works but just wondered if its the best way to do this

Comment: You're just doing the same thing 3 times.

Comment: `$('#input1')` will only get that one HTML Element by id.

Comment: 3 if statements is a good solution. although I'd put it on only 3 lines. there's way too much space in your example

Comment: @gibb2017 The names of the fields in the example are the same. Perhaps you meant `#input1`, `#input2`, `#input3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.each()` to check every input and if it's empty - assign corresponding value from an array holding the values.

```js
var inputs = ['something here', 'something else here', 'something else 2 here'];
    
    $('input').each(function(i){
      $(this).val() == '' ? $(this).val(inputs[i]) : null;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input1' value='x'>
<input id='input2'>
<input id='input3'>
```

```js
var inputs = {input1:'something here', input2:'something else here', input3: 'something else 2 here'};
    
    $('input').each(function(i){
      $(this).val() == '' ? $(this).val(inputs[$(this).attr('id')]) : null;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='input1' value='x'>
<input id='input2'>
<input id='input3'>
```

Comment: The order matter in this answer. That is not ideal.

Comment: The order in the array has to match the order of the html elements in the dom.

Comment: @MyiEye Doesn't it matches the order? I can't see the problem

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's just not as generic a solution as it could be. If someone with 10 inputs wanted to use this answer it would be significantly more complicated than using a solution where the order is irrelevant.

Comment: @MyiEye Is it that really complicated to add new elements into the array? Anyways - do you see the text appearing over the *downvote* button? *This answer is not useful*. Is it?

Comment: In this answers when rearranging the inputs in the html, you would also need to rearrange the defaults values in the js array accordingly. 

If each input has different purpose, that knowledge should be kept by an identifier on it. Why not keep the id of the inputs also in the array ?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object with keys the ids of your html elements and values their default values:

```
var inputDefaultValues = {
    "input1": "something here",
    "input2": "something else here",
    "input3":  "something else 2 here"
};
```

Then you could loop through the keys of this object, check if the value of the corresponding element is empty and if it is empty to aplly the default value:

```
Object.keys(inputDefaultValues)
      .forEach(function(key){
          var inputElement = document.getElementById(key);
          if(inputElement.value === ''){
              inputElement.value = inputDefaultValues[key];
          }
      });
```

```js
var inputDefaultValues = {
    "input1": "something here",
    "input2": "something else here",
    "input3":  "something else 2 here"
};

Object.keys(inputDefaultValues)
      .forEach(function(key){
          var inputElement = document.getElementById(key);
          if(inputElement.value === ''){
              inputElement.value = inputDefaultValues[key];
          }
      });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" id="input2"/>
<input type="text" id="input3"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this - the order doesn't matter, super flexible and super compact.

```
var defaults = {
   "#input1": "something here",
   "#input2": "...",
   "#input3": "..."
};

for (var id in defaults) {
   var currVal = $(id).val();
   $(id).val(currVal.trim() || defaults[id]);
}
```

Comment: Can I have a reason for a dv? :-D

Comment: this answer seems to be precise and generic

Answer (score 0):

We can extract an abstraction over the operation of checking the fields and putting the default value.

```
var fields = [{
    selector: "#input1",
    defaultVal: "default1"
}, {
    selector: "#input2",
    defaultVal: "default2"
}, {
    selector: "#input3",
    defaultVal: "default3"
}
];

var setDefault = function (selector, default) {
    if($(selector).val() == '') {
        $(selector).val(default);
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var field = fields[i];
    setDefault(field.selector, field.defaultVal);
}
```

Comment: `setDefault` is not doing anything actually. you missed default assignment

Comment: @YogeshMistry This is an example of implementing the pattern. As in the comment, the assignment will go after the comment ` //Add inputText to it`

Comment: Ok. I was just expecting the line `$(selector)`.val(default);` too

Comment: @YogeshMistry Yours is a valid request. You are free in SO to add editions to the answers that you think will help others and clarify the intent of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with simple `forEach` and `querySelector()` for pure javascript

```js
var input1text = 'something here';
var input2text = 'something else here';
var input3text = 'something else 2 here';

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(a,b){
a.value = a.value ?  a.value :window['input'+(b+1)+'text'] ;
})
```

```html
<input id="1" value="dddddddd"><input id="2"><input id="3">
```